# Product price calculator isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating an order form in which users can select an amount of products and it should immediately change total prices. I made some HTML markup and jquery code to achieve this, but I can't get it working. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try to use `$(this)` instead of `this`? And `this.next()` is probably not finding anything because it is in a different `td`. So you might want to use `$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]')`;

Comment: try `$(this).val()` OR `this.value`

Comment: What error are you getting? BTW, use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt` as your prices aren't integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed script:

```
$("input[type=number]").change(function () {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).attr("title"));
    var total = (value * this.value).toFixed(2);
    if (total < 0) total = 0;
    $(this).parent().next().find("input").val('€' + total);
});
```

Inside of event handler `this` refers to HTMLInputElement, not jQuery instance so you have to wrap it in `$(this)`.

Also you need to traverse one level up to the parent node and then use `next()` to get target  input field.

Finally I added basic validation to prevent negative prices. You can also add `min="0"` attribute to input fields.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/X33pS/

Comment: This is the correct answer. None of other answer are working. +1